Two ways to produce natural transformations
Let $\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}$ be two categories. Let $F_1,F_2\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ be functors from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$, $G_1,G_2\colon\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{C}$ be functors from $\mathcal{D}$ to $\mathcal{C}$.
Suppose $F_1$ is left adjoint to $G_1$, $G_2$ is left adjoint to $F_2$, i.e. we have adjoint pairs of functors $(F_1,G_1),(G_2,F_1)$. Let $\epsilon_1\colon F_1G_1\to 1_{\mathcal{D}}$, $\epsilon_2\colon G_2F_2\to 1_{\mathcal{C}}$ be the units, and $\eta_1\colon 1_{\mathcal{C}}\to G_1F_1$, $\eta_2\colon 1_{\mathcal{D}}\to F_2G_2$ be the counits.
Let $\Phi\colon G_1\to G_2$ be a natural transformation. Now we get the following diagram

I believe it is commutative, but I don't know how to prove it. Hope somebody can help.

There is no reason the diagram should commute in general.
For a counterexample, take $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{D} = \mathbf{Set}$, $F_1 = G_1 = 1$, $G_2 = X \times -, F_2 = [X, -]$ for some set $X$, and $\Phi = (x, -) : 1 \to X \times -$ for some element $x : X$. Then the "top" path takes $f : [X, Y]$ to $x' \mapsto (x', f(x)) : [X, X \times Y]$ while the "bottom" path takes $f$ to $x' \mapsto (x, f(x'))$.

Thank you Naïm, this really challenges my naive understanding of ``naturality''. Is there any chance for this to be true if I further require the composition G_1 F_2 to G_2 F_2 to 1 is identity and that the composition 1 to G_1 F_1 to G_2 F_1 is identity?

I don't understand what you mean by that. What composition? How can a morphism between different functors be the identity? Do you mean invertible?

Sorry, I mean the compositions are isomorphisms in the category of functors from C to D (D to C).

I don't know, that seems a bit random. I still don't know why you'd expect the diagram to commute, but now it seems much harder to come up with a counterexample.

My motivation comes from the six operation formalism. For example, let us consider constructible sheaves on topological spaces. Suppose j: U to X is an open inclusion of topological spaces, then we have adjoint pairs of functors $(j_!, j^!), (j^, j_)$ Moreover, $j^!=j^$ in this case. Therefore, by the above formal construction, one can construct two natural transformations from $j_!$ to $j_$, which I suppose should be the same.

Is this a Wirthmüller context? I don't follow how the $F_1 \circ G_1 \circ F_2 \Rightarrow F_2 \circ G_2 \circ F_1$ from your question corresponds to $j_! \Rightarrow j_*$ here.

In my case, $j^!\circ j_\simeq 1$ and $j^\circ j_!\simeq 1$, so you should watch the diagram in a mirror and consider the natural transformation from $F_1$ to $F_2$.
